# Hortonworks Hadoop using Virtualbox - Execute a jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, hadoop, jar

i am a hadoop beginner. Therefore i try to handle easy examples to get to know the environment. So i created a jar that performs a wordcount - amongst others this one [Hadoop: Set up Maven project in 5 Minutes](https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/05/25/setup-maven-project-for-hadoop-in-5mn/). My problem: It is not possible for me to execute the .jar at my Hortonworks Sandbox. Every time i get the error:

> WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications.
>   Not a valid JAR: /user/maria_dev/wordcount3.jar

To launch the jar i did the following steps:

1. Create the java classes in eclipse using maven projects.
2. Export a runnable jar file.
3. Load the jar into HDFS (using Ambari).
4. Call the jar using (with root-user, also trying with and without ssh):

`hadoop jar /user/maria_dev/wordcount3.jar /user/maria_dev/BlackArrow.txt /user/maria_dev`/

AND

```
hadoop jar /user/maria_dev/wordcount3.jar de.kja. wordcount3. wordcount /user/maria_dev/BlackArrow.txt /user/maria_dev/
```

In Both cases i get the error from above...

So i had the following thoughts:

1. My java class has an error -> I tried diverse other examples, all do not work. But trying to run the main class of each java file as java application i get one of the following errors:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>       at de.kja.wordcount2.wordcount.main(wordcount.java:47)

OR

> > Usage: WordCount [generic options]   Generic options supported are
> >     -conf      specify an application configuration file
> >     -D             use value for given property
> >     -fs       specify a namenode
> >     -jt     specify a job tracker
> >     -files     specify comma separated files to be copied to the map reduce cluster
> >     -libjars     specify comma separated jar files to include in the classpath.
> >     -archives     specify comma separated archives to be unarchived on the compute machines. The
> >     general command line syntax is bin/hadoop command [genericOptions]
> >     [commandOptions]

2. I read that the jar file does not have to be uploaded to the HDFS. So do have to load it to the local files of the virtual box? If yes: How can i do this?

Hadoop version: 2.7.1.2.4.0.0-169

If you need more information please ask! Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

In your virtual machine, open the Linux terminal

su - ambari-qa

yarn jar /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar teragen 1000 /tmp/genout

yarn jar /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar terasort /tmp/genout /tmp/sortout

yarn jar /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar teravalidate /tmp/sortout /tmp/valout

This is a sample to ensure you able to run jobs from sandbox.

you need to run your code as yarn jar ....

Comment: Thank you for your help! Sadfuly i can not run the jars. I got an error that said that this jar does not exist:

`[root@sandbox ~]# su - ambari-qa[ambari-qa@sandbox ~]$ yarn jar /usr/iop/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar teragen 1000 /tmp/genout         Not a valid JAR: /usr/iop/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar
[ambari-qa@sandbox ~]$ cd /
[ambari-qa@sandbox /]$ cd usr
[ambari-qa@sandbox usr]$ ls
bin  etc  games  hdp  include  lib  lib64  libexec  local  sbin  share  src  tmp
[ambari-qa@sandbox usr]$`

Comment: I updated the path in my above comment. The path is /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/.